# Append data to an already existing pandas dataframe in a for-loop

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, append

I have two dataframes `data` and `quantiles`. Both datasets contains the columns 'State' and 'Year'. If these are equal in both pandas dataframe, I subset the `data` on the column `fPAR` if the value in the column `quantile` in the `quantiles` is larger than the values in the `fPAR`. Herafter, I find the correlation between the column `fPAR` and `mPAR` in the subset of the `data`.

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/data.csv')
quantiles = pd.read_csv('C:/percentiles_t.csv')
merged_df = data.merge(quantiles, on=['State', 'Year'])

# Filter the merged dataframe based on 'fPAR' and 'quantile' columns
subset_df = merged_df.loc[merged_df['fPAR'] < merged_df['fPAR_y']]

# Group the subset dataframe by 'State' and 'Year'
grouped_df = subset_df.groupby(['State', 'Year', 'quantiles'])

# Loop over each group and calculate the correlation between 'fPAR' and 'mPAR'
for (State, Year, quantile), group_df in grouped_df:
    corr = group_df['fPAR'].corr(group_df['mPAR'])
    t.append(corr)
    print(f"State: {State}, Year: {year}, Quantile: {quantile}, Correlation: {corr}")
```

I can print the data into the console, but I would like to append every `corr` value find to the correct `State` and `year` in the `quantiles` dataframe.
I have tried:

```
# Loop over each group and calculate the correlation between 'fPAR' and 'mPAR'
for (State, Year, quantile), group_df in grouped_df:
    corr = group_df['fPAR'].corr(group_df['mPAR'])
    quantiles['corr'].append(corr)
    print(f"State: {State}, Year: {year}, Quantile: {quantile}, Correlation: {corr}")
```

How do I do that?